# display java script object content in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have this node-mysql query that I output to a js object:

```
var queryString = 'SELECT usrFirstName, usrLastName FROM USR';

connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in rows) {
        arr[i] = JSON.stringify(rows[i]);
    }
    console.log(arr)
```

The output is:

```
[ '{"usrFirstName":"Joey","usrLastName":"Thade"}',
  '{"usrFirstName":"Thomas","usrLastName":"Jacobs"}',
  '{"usrFirstName":"Danny","usrLastName":"Elerrd"}' ]
```

Now, I'm trying to get the specific info of a specific column. Using arr[0] I get the first row, but how can I access specific columns in it?

Comment: did you try this arr[0].usrFirstName

Comment: Can't just looking for specific `usrFirstName`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Why do you stringify it if you want to access the properties later?

Comment: as for are[0].usrFirstName - it return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was - just don't stringify.

```
arr[i] = rows[i];
```

Thanks everybody.